# WordPress PHP disable element

Tags: php, css, wordpress, storefront

**I want to disable save&share button**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-none btn-sm btn-save-design dg-tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Save &amp; Share" onclick="design.save()">
                <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
            </button>
```

**I tried to hide using**

```
.btn-save-design {display: none;}
```

**And**

```
.btn-save-design {display: none;}//first.btn{//other style...}
```

**And also**

```
.btn-save-design {display: none !important;}
```

**And also**

```
.btn-save-design i.fa.fa-save {
 display:none;}
```

**But nothing happens**

**Screenshot** >>> https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8570.jpg

**Any suggestions for PHP code?**

Comment: It's impossible for us to give you a PHP suggestion since we have no idea where or how that HTML is outputted. We also don't know the hierarchy of the HTML or default CSS, so it's pretty hard to suggest that as well. If that code is outputted by a plugin, you could just disable it. If you've put the code there, just remove it?

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify your HTML, try using :

```
<button disabled>
```

Comment: Since the question is tagged with Wordpress, I bet that HTML is outputted by some plugin, which usually means that you really can't change the HTML output.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways you can fix this issue:

1) Add a prevent default on the button on click, using javascript or jquery.

```
$( "your-element" ).click(function( e ) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

2) Using styles to set the button to display none, (you may have to add an ID to this save icon to overwrite the other styles)

this url will explain to you all about css priorities:

https://marksheet.io/css-priority.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Please put the exact code, because I'm not a developer and I will put it in a path you provided

Comment: updated my answer with some exact code for you, let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is down to [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). By default those buttons will have `display: block` / `display: inline-block` as their default value. You can beat this by doing:

```
button.btn-save-design {
    display: none
}
```

This is because `button.class` is more specific than `.class` and thus the style is applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the onclick attribute of that element with jQuery.
Add this somewhere in the theme:

```
$(".btn-save-design").prop("onclick", null).off("click");
```

This line will delete the onclick attribute of the button.